# How are social network graphs implemented ? Adjacency List or Adjacency Matrix

Tags: graph, social-networking, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

Specifically , my question is how do social networks like Facebook implement their relationship graphs.

Since there are lot of operations that query relationships, Adjacency Matrix is a good idea. But then the graph is growing so fast day by day as new people make accounts. So Adjacency Matrix can lead to lot of space wastage.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question as you did. Almost all the resources I found said that it depends on the "density" of the graph. Use adjacency list for sparse graph, adjacency Matrix for dense graph. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph), density of undirected simple graph is :

```
2*|E| / |V| * (|V|-1)
```

from the small set of Facebook data i got, the density is about 0.008 which is relatively sparse I guess. So maybe adjacency list is better in social network like Facebook (undirected graph).